# How to prevent sasl_username root from loggin in?

Tags: postfix

My Postfix server keeps getting used by spammers. Here is the output of `sudo postcat -vq` for the last spam message caught:

```
└──> sudo postcat -vq 3513818A8A
postcat: name_mask: all
postcat: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
postcat: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv6 addresses
*** ENVELOPE RECORDS deferred/3/3513818A8A ***
message_size:            8412             720               1               0            8412
message_arrival_time: Thu Aug 19 13:35:50 2021
create_time: Thu Aug 19 13:35:50 2021
named_attribute: log_ident=3513818A8A
named_attribute: rewrite_context=remote
named_attribute: sasl_method=LOGIN
named_attribute: sasl_username=root
sender: xfinity@fitprobands.com
named_attribute: log_client_name=unknown
named_attribute: log_client_address=93.122.252.4
named_attribute: log_client_port=16374
named_attribute: log_message_origin=unknown[93.122.252.4]
named_attribute: log_helo_name=109-166-129-221.orangero.net
named_attribute: log_protocol_name=ESMTP
named_attribute: client_name=unknown
named_attribute: reverse_client_name=unknown
named_attribute: client_address=93.122.252.4
named_attribute: client_port=16374
named_attribute: helo_name=109-166-129-221.orangero.net
named_attribute: protocol_name=ESMTP
named_attribute: client_address_type=2
named_attribute: dsn_orig_rcpt=rfc822;conyers811@comcast.net
original_recipient: conyers811@comcast.net
recipient: conyers811@comcast.net
```

[Based on these two lines](https://serverfault.com/questions/1073807/how-to-prevent-unauthorized-mails-sent-from-my-mail-server/1074303):

```
named_attribute: sasl_method=LOGIN
named_attribute: sasl_username=root
```

I believe the spammer is successfully logging as `root` and then sending their spam messages out of my server. And that's confirmed by running `sudo cat /var/log/maillog | grep sasl_username=root` which shows lot's of entries like:

```
Aug 19 17:13:15 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: EA58D18CCD: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:17 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: BDA4E18D32: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:19 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: 7387E18D31: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:21 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: 1C0FB18D34: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:22 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: DCB4418D36: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:24 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: B62DD18D39: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:26 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: 6F52B18D38: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:28 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: 24DEF18D3A: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:29 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: A30B418D3C: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:31 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: 88D8318D3B: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
Aug 19 17:13:33 mail postfix/smtpd[11442]: 11F6118D44: client=unknown[93.122.252.4], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
```

I have Dovecot running on the server besides Postfix, so checking the `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` files shows:

```
# Valid UID range for users, defaults to 500 and above. This is mostly
# to make sure that users can't log in as daemons or other system users.
# Note that denying root logins is hardcoded to dovecot binary and can't
# be done even if first_valid_uid is set to 0.
first_valid_uid = 1000
#last_valid_uid = 0
```

So I'm now lost how exactly the spammer is managing to authenticate as `root`. Goes without saying the `root` user is disabled on the system.

Any suggestions how to completely prevent sasl_username `root` from logging into the system?

Comment: I suspect you  are not using Dovecot to validate sasl logins. The output of the command `postconf smtpd_sasl_type` will tell. I also doubt that you have a good reason to accept authenticated submissions on port 25 (the line starting `smtp inet`), so review your master.cf and ensure that `-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes` only appears attached to services meant for submission (the line starting `smtps inet` and optionally `submission inet`).

Comment: You were right: running `postconf smtpd_sasl_type` has pointed to `cyrus`. But then searching for `cyrus` on the system shows some entries in `selinux` (which is disabled) and some in `/usr/share/doc/`, so no any configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing who setup that system that way and why, I cannot give specific recommendation. But I can say that the overwhelming majority of servers where Dovecot handles IMAP authentication are well served by letting Dovecot also handle SMTP authentication, and that is how your Dovecot configuration `first_valid_uid` would become effective for mail submission as well.

Read [the relevant documentation](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/) and then consider configuring your Postfix to defer authentication to Dovecot, typically these lines in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
```

Additionally, consider setting `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no` in `main.cf` and removing the first `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes` up in your `master.cf`. Authentication is typically only desirable for services meant for submission (the line starting smtps inet and optionally submission inet), so it should be enabled only for one or two such services via `master.cf`. This would break clients that use port 25 to submit authenticated mail - but such clients configuration probably need review anyway if you are changing onfiguration.

Comment: Once *new* submission are properly restricted, you still have to deal with previously submitted and still queued mail, for that you likely want to use [postsuper](https://serverfault.com/search?q=postsuper).

Comment: The system came set in that way together with Webmin/Virtualmin. Setting `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=` to `no` in line that starts with `smtp` in master.cf file seems to have stopped all undesired sasl auth attempts, at the same time giving legitimate users to continue to use their mail clients. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user102362 Just to be super clear here: Disabling the authentication features on one particular port where it is unnecessary may stop one particular bot abusing your misconfigured authentication setup - *but you still must fix* your authentication configuration, as your server could still be abused that way on the other ports used by legitimate user!

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have had exactly the same on my uptodate Ubuntu box. I am sure I had smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot and smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth set.

I have the same question as user102362 has: when I read this in my config:

```
# Note that denying root logins is hardcoded to dovecot binary and can't
# be done even if first_valid_uid is set to 0.
```

I assume that its not possible to authenticate as root. But then, WHY is this possible:

```
Jan 19 21:16:46 VPS postfix/smtpd[9392]: EF1B6BD5B8: client=unknown[213.233.y.x], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=root
```

and resulted in sending lots of unsolicited mail?

Coincidence or not, the (successful) SASL authentications came from the same country and operator, so I decided to block the following blocks completely:

```
93.122.128.0/17
213.233.88.0/24
46.97.176.0/21
178.138.64.0/18
109.166.128.0/17
```

And I changed the root (and other accounts) password.

Comment: Similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1073807/how-to-prevent-unauthorized-mails-sent-from-my-mail-server

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `first_valid_uid` only affects Dovecot's userdb lookup in passwd database and does not impact the passdb lookup. After delving into the source files, it becomes clear that the validity check takes place in the `passwd_iterate_want_pw` function located in the file `core/src/auth/userdb-passwd.c`:

```c
static bool passwd_iterate_want_pw(struct passwd *pw, const struct auth_settings *set) {
    /* Skip entries not in the valid UID range.
       They're users for daemons and such. */
    if (pw->pw_uid < (uid_t)set->first_valid_uid)
        return FALSE;
    if (pw->pw_uid > (uid_t)set->last_valid_uid && set->last_valid_uid != 0)
        return FALSE;
    if (pw->pw_gid < (gid_t)set->first_valid_gid)
        return FALSE;
    if (pw->pw_gid > (gid_t)set->last_valid_gid && set->last_valid_gid != 0)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

If the function returns FALSE, the userdb lookup will skip that user, resulting in an error stating that the user is not found.

However, during the passdb lookup, a separate database is used to verify the username and password. Taking the default driver `pam` as an example, its configuration file is located at `/etc/pam.d/dovecot`, and lookup is performed in `/etc/shadow`. The passdb lookup does not involve checking the validity of the username with the passwd database for userdb.

When the `auth_debug = yes` setting is enabled in Dovecot's configuration file, here is an example of logs generated during an smtpd authentication:

```
1111-11-11T11:11:41.122920+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0114#011plain#011service=smtp#011nologin#011lip=127.0.0.1#011rip=127.0.0.1.87#011secured
1111-11-11T11:11:41.123831+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT#0114#011
1111-11-11T11:11:43.185585+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: CONT<hidden>
1111-11-11T11:11:43.185703+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth: Debug: pam(root,127.0.0.1.87): Performing passdb lookup
1111-11-11T11:11:43.194570+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
1111-11-11T11:11:43.195187+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/lib20_auth_var_expand_crypt.so
1111-11-11T11:11:43.195807+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=37547,uid=107): Server accepted connection (fd=13)
1111-11-11T11:11:43.196014+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=37547,uid=107): Sending version handshake
1111-11-11T11:11:43.196326+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=37547,uid=107): auth-worker<1>: Handling PASSV request
1111-11-11T11:11:43.196575+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=37547,uid=107): auth-worker<1>: pam(root,127.0.0.1.87): Performing passdb lookup
1111-11-11T11:11:43.196757+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=37547,uid=107): auth-worker<1>: pam(root,127.0.0.1.87): lookup service=dovecot
1111-11-11T11:11:43.199784+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth-worker(37592): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=37547,uid=107): auth-worker<1>: pam(root,127.0.0.1.87): #1/1 style=1 msg=Password: 
1111-11-11T11:11:45.306854+00:00 myserver dovecot: auth: Debug: pam(root,127.0.0.1.87): Finished passdb lookup
```

As you can see, only the `pam` module is called throughout the process, and there is no module to determine the validity of the user like the `passwd` module. Consequently, the `root` user can pass the SMTPD authentication as long as the password is correct and can send emails without any issues, although they won't be able to receive emails.

Considering the security vulnerabilities that enabling password login for the root user brings, it is advisable to run the command `passwd -l root` to disable the password for `root`. This command sets an impossible value for the `root` user's password in the `/etc/shadow` file. Consequently, no matter what password is attempted for `root` in SASL, the `pam` module will return an error `Authentication failure (Password mismatch?)`, thus preventing `root` from logging in via SASL.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. In our case, it turned out that the root password had been inadvertantly removed (`passwd -d root` -- whereas we should have run `passwd -l root`). This did not permit root ssh logins fortunately (`PermitRootLogin no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), but it did allow spammers to log as root to the email server and send spam.

The problem stopped when we disabled the root password with `passwd -l root`.